# Nixos can't install ruby2d gem

Tags: ruby, linux, rubygems, nixos, ruby2d

[output](https://pastebin.com/yyuk1eYx)
[shell.nix](https://pastebin.com/PZx5m7Y0)

When i execute `gem install ruby2d` in my `nix-shell` it can't, because nix has no fhs. Can u help me?

Comment: Why should one [not upload images of error and code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to install `libGL` using the following script:

```hs
{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {} }:
 
(pkgs.buildFHSUserEnv {
  name = "env";
  targetPkgs = pkgs: (with pkgs;
  [
    ruby_3_0
    bundler
    rake
    SDL.dev
    SDL2.dev
    SDL2_image
    SDL2_mixer
    SDL2_ttf
    libGL
 
    gccStdenv
    stdenv
    rbenv
    ]);
  runScript = "bash";
}).env
```